# GRH versus RH - Big picture

Tags: riemann-hypothesis, big-picture

What is the relation between generalized Riemann Hypothesis and Riemann Hypothesis?

Does proving one have implication the other?

Are there results which implies failure of one to failure of other?

Are there any results which needs both hypothesis?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis to get started with your first question.

Comment: Why doesn't the wikipedia article answer all your questions?